# How can I run xautolock as a service?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, systemd

### What I'm trying to do

Okay so I've been trying to create a custom lockscreen on ubuntu using i3lock.
I achieved something I'm comfortable with as a lockscreen, but now I want to use this lockscreen instead of the default gnome one.

So I'm using xautolock for that, which works well when typed in a terminal, but that means I have to enter this manually each time I turn my pc on.
So right now I'm trying to making it a systemd service, and that's where I struggle.

### What I block on

First thing is: executing the xautolock command in a shell script doesn't even work.

```
`#!/bin/bash
`xautolock -time 1 -locker mylock.sh #this line works in CLI but suspend the console
```

(I've done a chess game on my phone to wait, it lasted way longer than a minute and it didn't do anything whereas executing it in terminal works well)

So there is this problem, but wait there is more!

I've done the .service file, and running mylock.sh from the service returns an exit status=1/FAILURE.

Thus my incomprehension, because the line works in the console, and executing the shell script manually blocks the console aswell so I assume it doesn't fail (it doesn't work as expected tho)

I've tried two different configs for the service:
First one with `ExecStart=/usr/bin/xautolock -time 1 -locker <path_to_my_lock>/mylock.sh`
Which outputs (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

In the other one I tried to executed the a "lockservice.sh" script containing the `xautolock` line (which has no chance to work given the previous tests):
`ExecStart=/bin/bash /PATH/lockservice.sh`
Same thing: (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

**I did a `systemctl daemon-reload` everytime, I chmoded 755 all the shell scripts. I also tried to execute the service with `User=root`**

### What I would like

I basically want something that can replace the gnome default lockscreen with my custom lock script, using xautolock and services isn't mandatory to me, but I'd like not having to run it manually on startup.

Thanks in advance !